# How do I create a list of random strings value without duplicates?

Tags: python

How to generate random string of my list without duplication in python?
i tried using random.sample but it keeps sending me duplicates sometimes.

```
import random 


column_arr = ['id', 'name', 'location', 'duration'
, 'id', 'name', 'quantity', 'unit'
, 'id', 'description', 'unit', 'quantity', 'unit_cost']


arr = []
for i in range(3):
      arr.append(random.choice(column_arr))
print(arr)
```

Comment: Question: do you mean you'd like to remove the duplicates from `column_arr` before sampling from it, or do you mean you want to make sure the resulting `arr` has no duplicates in it?

Comment: I want to make sure that my resulting arr has no duplicates in it.

Answer (score 2):

Not sure why you’re doing this, but sets can help you here.

```
import random 
column_arr = ['id', 'name', 'location', 'duration'
    , 'id', 'name', 'quantity', 'unit'
    , 'id', 'description', 'unit', 'quantity', 'unit_cost']

arr = []
for i in range(3):
    arr.append(random.choice(set(column_arr)))
print(arr)
```

Comment: This code does not work: `TypeError: 'set' object is not subscriptable`, and how would it solve the duplicates, even if it did?

Comment: hi i tried your suggestion but i get some errors ; TypeError: 'set' object is not subscriptable

Comment: You’re right, sorry it should be list(set(column_arr))

Comment: Sets are collections that [do not contain duplicates](https://docs.python.org/3/tutorial/datastructures.html#sets)

Comment: @KeoniGarner Yes, set removes the duplicates from the input, but repeated sampling over that set can resample the same item more than once, so there's no guarantee `arr` will not have duplicates.

Comment: @joanis Good point. This should not be considered the answer

Answer (score 2):

you could use `random.choice` inside `numpy`. It allows you to choice from array or other iterables. n elements, and selecting if you want repetition or not.

besides that, your `column_arr` has repetitions so you will have to convert it in a set. so wrapping up:

```
import numpy as np


column_arr = ['id', 'name', 'location', 'duration'
, 'id', 'name', 'quantity', 'unit'
, 'id', 'description', 'unit', 'quantity', 'unit_cost']


column_arr_set = set(column_arr) #this eliminates duplicates by converting in set
arr = np.random.choice(list(column_arr_set), 3,replace=False)
```

For last you can set `replace` flag to `True` or just delete it to have repetitions:

`arr_with_reps = np.random.choice(list(column_arr_set),3) #this allows repetitions.`

---

**Edit **
Thanks to Joanis for the corrections (needs replace=False in first choice, and convert column_arr_set to list before calling

Comment: You need `list(column_arr_set)` in there, otherwise I get `ValueError: a must be 1-dimensional or an integer`

Comment: And you'll need to add `replace=False` to that `np.random.choice()` call, so sampling is done without replacement, as OP clarified they need.

Comment: corrections made, thanks!

Answer (score 1):

The duplicate values in your list are causing random.sample() to produce duplicates.  If you convert it to a set beforehand, you will not get duplicates:

```
import random 

column_arr = ['id', 'name', 'location', 'duration'
, 'id', 'name', 'quantity', 'unit'
, 'id', 'description', 'unit', 'quantity', 'unit_cost']

arr = random.sample(set(column_arr),3)
print(arr)

['id', 'unit', 'quantity']
```

If the repeated values in the list are meant to increase the probability of certain strings, then you can shuffle the list and take the first 3 unique values (which you can extract using a dictionary constructor):

```
random.shuffle(column_arr)
arr = list(dict.fromkeys(column_arr).keys())[:3]
```